# send application delegate message to current view without notification center

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsnotificationcenter, appdelegate

I want to display **application delegate** message such as "Application became active" (This is called when `-applicationDidBecomeActive:application` is called)
 on Window.

One way is to use notification center like below:

**AppDelegate.m**

```
NSNotification *n = [NSNotification notificationWithName:@"AppBecameActive" object:self];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:n];
```

**ViewController.m**

```
NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[nc addObserver:self selector:@selector(showMessageAppBecameActive) name:@"AppBecameActive" object:nil];
```

This way is **only** way to show application delegate message ? Or, is there any other way such as property to look current view controller instance ?

Thank you for your kindness.

Comment: I don't want to use **notification center** because it make code complex. If there is some way such as some property to use, I want to use it.

Comment: My take is that in the general case, using properties will make your code far more complex than using `NSNotificationCenter`. But you could always add a `ViewController` property to `AppDelegate` and send it a message directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the **ViewController** from your **appDelegate**. (I mean like @property or instance is reside in it) you can straight away send a message. If you do not have such access to it. write **key value observer** for a single ton and let your **viewController** receive the change.

Answer (score -1):

Register below code in your viewController which wants notification.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(yourMethod)
                                             name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

iOS framework posts a notification when your app become active, if you will register via above way, you can handle the notification in registered method (In this case yourMethod).